# Why are my routes working locally but not on my live site?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I suspect this is not a code issue as the issue only occurs live and there are no console errors or anything else to indicate otherwise. If code examples are needed, I will share.

**Objective:** Allow visitors to view specific components on my site depending on the URL. This is achieved using `react-router-dom`.

It all works flawlessly locally but once it's live, it hits a 404 page. No errors when I test locally. I cannot recreate the problem locally so I don't really understand how to trouble shoot it.

**Steps to recreate the problem:**

1. Navigate to https://wordplayideas.com/
2. For every idea on the homepage, you can find a share button which you can click to go to a specific thing on the website(e.g. https://wordplayideas.com/russell-brands-mussell-bran) which displays as expected when going through the UI of the site. See below:

[image]

3. Copy and paste that URL into any browser or simply refresh the page and it hits a specific 404 page. See below:

[image]

4. If you manual put a typo into the URL locally, it directs to my custom 404 page which would at least be the expected behaviour on my live site. See below:

[image]

Comment: @Phil No luck. I tried using hash router as a catch all and it didn't work. I've since found other people online with the same issue and I still can't figure this out.

Comment: _"I tried using hash router as a catch all"_... I don't know what that means but the thing you're missing is server-side URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Phil who responded to my initial question which eventually led me to finding the answer [here](https://dev.to/crishanks/deploy-host-your-react-app-with-cpanel-in-under-5-minutes-4mf6).

I may have asked the question incorrectly. Something I may have needed to include in my question is that I am deploying my site via cPanel. I would run `npm run build` and then upload the build files to the root folder of my website.

The solution was to include a `.htaccess` file with the following in the root folder of my site. For most people this would be `public_html`.

Inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Once this file was uploaded, the routing worked just as it does locally.
Hope it helps anyone else in a similar situation.